# Executes when startPoint and endPoint are in same road

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, routes, mysql-spatial

Can you suggest the code to find the routing when the `startpoint` and `endpoint` are in the same road in sql server

```
SET @e = (
        SELECT TOP 1 a.target
        FROM   Routes a
        WHERE  a.geom.STIntersects(geometry::Point(@endLon ,@endLat ,4326).STBuffer(0.002)) = 
               1
        ORDER BY
               geometry::Point(@endLon ,@endLat ,4326).STDistance(a.geom)
    );
```